# Adjust vba to newly inserted column

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a code which gets triggered by the client clicking on a specific cell:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B3")) Is Nothing Then
`do code
```

On B3 in the excel sheet it says *click here*

Now the issue is that my client is very reluctant to follow instructions on not adding new rows or cells.
Which means as soon as a new row or column is added (shifting the cell value B3 to say C3) the code is not triggered by the *click here* cell any longer, but still by B3.

This is further complicated by other codes being triggered in a similar fashion:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("AM7:AM48")) Is Nothing Then
```

Is there a way to dynamically adjust the code to the adjustments by my client?

Comment: Is using named ranges an option? They move with the cell.

Comment: Yes! I didn't know that was a thing, so Thank you very much!! Now how do I mark that as the correct answer?